# How to pass an parameter between various message events

Tags: java, netty

I would like to pass an object between various channel events in the handler. This object is created per message. So once it is set, it should be available for the various events that occur for this message. (I'm trying to build a HTTP server). Please let me know weather it is possible to do this?

Does `ChannelHandlerContext.setAttachement()` will work?

Answer (score 1):

`ChannelHandlerContext.setAttachment(...)` will work as long as you don't need to access it from different handlers. If you need to access it from different handlers you will need to use s static `ChannelLocal` instance for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another question, I have to set this object when a connection is established by the ClientBosstrap.connect. How can I do this?

Comment: You can add your own handler which extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler and override the channelConnected(...) method. There you can set the attachment.